# SQLite inconsistency behavior with the NOT operator

Tags: sql, sqlite, type-conversion, where-clause, operator-precedence

As for example, I am using this website: https://sqliteonline.com/.

I try to fuzz around with queries and did as such:

```sql
SELECT * FROM demo
WHERE Name="SQL " || "Online"
```

Which correctly retrieved:

```
1-SQL Online-for Data Science
```

Now I tried to use the `AND` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM demo
WHERE Name="SQL " || "Online" AND Hint=1 IS NOT 2
```

which retrieved the same answer as before, because `1` is indeed not `2` thus it is `Query AND True=>True`.

But if I changed it to something else, let's say:

```
SELECT * FROM demo
WHERE Name="SQL " || "Online" AND Hint=1 IS NOT 1
```

It returns the same answer as before! even though `1 IS NOT 1` is completely false, as I've seen in this query:

```sql
SELECT *, 1 IS NOT 1 AS isTrue FROM demo
WHERE Name="SQL " || "Online" AND Hint=1 IS NOT 1
```

where `isTrue=0`

So this query is basically this one:

```sql
SELECT *, 1 IS NOT 1 AS isTrue FROM demo
WHERE Name="SQL " || "Online" AND Hint=0
```

But when I execute this query explicitly, it does not retrieve any results!

What is going on here? I would appreciate your help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Operators, and Parse-Affecting Attributes](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators_and_parse_affecting_attributes), your condition is equivalent to:

```
(Name=("SQL " || "Online")) AND ((Hint=1) IS NOT 2)
```

because of the operators precedence.

This means that it is the boolean expression `Hint=1` that is checked whether it is `2` or not.
A boolean expression like `Hint=1` is evaluated as `0` for `false` or `1` for `true`.

The column `Hint`'s values are strings and prior to the comparison with `1` or any numeric expression SQLite tries to convert them implicitly to numeric values, but since this is not possible they are converted to `0`, so, your condition is equivalent to:

```
(Name=("SQL " || "Online")) AND ((0=1) IS NOT 2)
```

and since `0=1` evaluates to `0`(= `false`):

```
(Name=("SQL " || "Online")) AND (0 IS NOT 2)
```

or:

```
(Name=("SQL " || "Online")) AND true
```

or:

```
Name="SQL " || "Online"
```

Note that you would get the same result with:

```
(Name=("SQL " || "Online")) AND ((Hint=1) IS NOT 1)
```

But, with

```
(Name=("SQL " || "Online")) AND ((Hint=1) IS NOT 0)
```

the result would be:

```
(Name=("SQL " || "Online")) AND false
```

which evaluates to just `false`.

Comment: But your last query does give me results and the same as the previous query

Comment: @RulerOfJustice no, it does not return results as you can see in the demo I provided. This is why I asked you in a comment under your question if you can reproduce the results that you claim you get.

Comment: Yes I can reproduce

Comment: @RulerOfJustice fine, post the link here so I can check.

Comment: The link is at the top of the question, copy and paste the queries I posted to reproduce

Comment: @RulerOfJustice I thought that the column Hint was the ID of the table because you compared it to 1 and 2. See my edited answer.